# Extract data from Json for ng-bootstrap typeahead

Tags: json, angular, ng-bootstrap

Trying to make Play Framework (REST) and [**`ng-bootstrap - Typeahead`**](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead) work together. But I'm facing a problem with extracting data from `json` response. For example I write "test" (searches in database by `name`), server returns json array(everything is right):

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "test",
  "annotation": "test annotation",
  "kiMin": 1,
  "kiMax": 2,
  "cosFiMin": 3,
  "cosFiMax": 4
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "name": "test2",
  "annotation": "test annotation",
  "kiMin": 1,
  "kiMax": 2,
  "cosFiMin": 3,
  "cosFiMax": 4
}]
```

But the view looks like this:

[image]

Here's my code:

**http.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Equipment }           from './equipment';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
  private Url = "http://localhost:9000/find?term=";  // URL to web API
  constructor (private http: Http) {}
  search ( term :String ): Observable<Equipment[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.Url+term)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || { };
  }
  private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

**ngb-typeahead-http.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {HttpService} from './http.service';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';


@Component({
  selector: 'ngb-typeahead-http',
  templateUrl: './typeahead-http.html',
  providers: [HttpService],
  styles: [`.form-control { width: 300px; display: inline; }`]
})
export class NgbTypeaheadHttp {
  model: any;
  searching = false;
       searchFailed = false;

    constructor(private _service: HttpService) {}

    search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
      text$
        .debounceTime(300)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .do(() => this.searching = true)
  .switchMap(term =>
    this._service.search(term)
        .do(() => this.searchFailed = false)
        .catch(() => {
          this.searchFailed = true;
          return Observable.of([]);
        }))
  .do(() => this.searching = false);
  }
```

**typeahead-http.html**

```html
<div class="form-group" [class.has-danger]="searchFailed">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search" placeholder="search" />
  <span *ngIf="searching">searching...</span>
  <div class="form-control-feedback" *ngIf="searchFailed">Sorry, suggestions could not be loaded.</div>
</div>
```

How could I extract data from json object? Any suggestions, please.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you're using objects with the typeahead you need to make use of the [inputFormatter] and [resultFormatter] inputs. For inputFormatter and resultFormatter you pass functions that take the object from your selection or results list and output the text value you want to display for that object.

Added function to component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngb-typeahead-http',
  templateUrl: './typeahead-http.html',
  providers: [HttpService],
  styles: [`.form-control { width: 300px; display: inline; }`]
})
export class NgbTypeaheadHttp {
  model: any;
  searching = false;
  searchFailed = false;

    constructor(private _service: HttpService) {}
    // Added
    formatMatches = (value: any) => value.name || '';
    search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
      text$
        .debounceTime(300)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .do(() => this.searching = true)
    .switchMap(term =>
      this._service.search(term)
          .do(() => this.searchFailed = false)
          .catch(() => {
            this.searchFailed = true;
            return Observable.of([]);
          }))
    .do(() => this.searching = false);
}
```

Passing function to typeahead inputs

```
<div class="form-group" [class.has-danger]="searchFailed">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
        [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search"
        placeholder="search" 
        [resultFormatter]="formatMatches"
        [inputFormatter]="formatMatches" />
    <span *ngIf="searching">searching...</span>
    <div class="form-control-feedback" *ngIf="searchFailed">Sorry, suggestions could not be loaded.</div>
</div>
```